# Is that safe to use functional components with hooks inside class based components in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question regarding the React Hooks and class based components. I've heard from some developers that **using functional components with React Hooks as a children of class based components may lead to some tricky bugs and that it's better to avoid doing so**. I don't have more information about that and didn't find any articles or something like that.

So does anyone knows if it's true or not?

And if it's true please give me some examples or at least explain that to me.

Comment: according to docs, it's safe to use function component with hooks inside class component https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main reason of it is that we should stick with one style per project. I mean it is better to use only hooks (new projects) or only class components (for example in older projects) because doing 2 similar things in the same time will be hard for not experienced developers. But this is only my personal opinion.

Regarding your problem I think you have mistook it with this sentence "You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component". That means you can not apply hook to class component, but it is safe to render hook based component inside class.